# Issues with make and #include

Tags: c, makefile

Somewhere between my headers and my `Makefile` I'm not doing the dependencies correctly, and it's not compiling. This really only has anything to do with the first few lines from each code, but I posted all the code for reference

I'm trying to split up a `who` clone into 3 parts. [Here is the original for reference](http://wps.prenhall.com/wps/media/objects/510/522376/Molay_Unix_SourceCode/ch02/who3.c). The exercise is to `make` it with utmp, so you [also need utmplib](http://wps.prenhall.com/wps/media/objects/510/522376/Molay_Unix_SourceCode/ch02/utmplib.c)

So I've split it up into 3 files, the first one being `show.h`

```
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <sys/types.h>
#include    <utmp.h>
#include    <fcntl.h>
#include    <time.h>
#include    <stdlib.h>
#define SHOWHOST

void show_info(struct utmp *);
void showtime(time_t);
```

then I have `show.c`

```
/*
 *  *   show info()
 *   *          displays the contents of the utmp struct
 *    *         in human readable form
 *     *            * displays nothing if record has no user name
 *      */
void show_info( struct utmp *utbufp )
{
    if ( utbufp->ut_type != USER_PROCESS )
        return;

    printf("%-8.8s", utbufp->ut_name);      /* the logname  */
    printf(" ");                    /* a space  */
    printf("%-8.8s", utbufp->ut_line);      /* the tty  */
    printf(" ");                    /* a space  */
    showtime( utbufp->ut_time );            /* display time */
#ifdef SHOWHOST
    if ( utbufp->ut_host[0] != '\0' )
        printf(" (%s)", utbufp->ut_host);   /* the host */
#endif
    printf("\n");                   /* newline  */
}

void showtime( time_t timeval )
/*
 *  *   displays time in a format fit for human consumption
 *   *  uses ctime to build a string then picks parts out of it
 *    *      Note: %12.12s prints a string 12 chars wide and LIMITS
 *     *      it to 12chars.
 *      */
{
    char    *ctime();       /* convert long to ascii    */
    char    *cp;            /* to hold address of time  */

    cp = ctime( &timeval );     /* convert time to string   */
                    /* string looks like        */
                    /* Mon Feb  4 00:46:40 EST 1991 */
                    /* 0123456789012345.        */
    printf("%12.12s", cp+4 );   /* pick 12 chars from pos 4 */
}
```

and finally, `who3.c'

```
/* who3.c - who with buffered reads
 *    - surpresses empty records
 *    - formats time nicely
 *    - buffers input (using utmplib)
 */
#include "show.h"

int main()
{
    struct utmp *utbufp,    /* holds pointer to next rec    */
            *utmp_next();   /* returns pointer to next  */

    if ( utmp_open( UTMP_FILE ) == -1 ){
        perror(UTMP_FILE);
        exit(1);
    }
    while ( ( utbufp = utmp_next() ) != ((struct utmp *) NULL) )
        show_info( utbufp );
    utmp_close( );
    return 0;
}
```

So I created my `Makefile`:

```
who3:who3.o utmplib.o
    gcc -o who who3.o utmplib.o
who3.o:who3.c show.c
    gcc -c who3.c show.o
show.o:show.c
    gcc -c show.c show.h
utmplib.o:utmplib.c
    gcc -c utmplib.c
clean:
    rm -f *.o
```

Unfortunately there's an error when I do `make`:

```
gcc -o who who3.o utmplib.o
who3.o: In function `main':
who3.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `show_info'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [who3] Error 1
```

As I said earlier, I haven't done my dependencies correctly, and I'm not sure what I did wrong. How do I do my dependencies correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are missing `show.o` from the dependencies *and* from the list of object files of the command for building `who3` in your makefile.

Also, the command for `who3.o` looks wrong. You are compiling only `-c`, but you are passing an object file as input (`show.o`). You should remove `show.o` from the rule and `show.c` doesn't belong on the list of dependencies of `who3.o` either.

Also, the command for `show.o` looks wrong. You shouldn't be passing header files (`show.h`) to the compiler; they only need to be referenced as `#include` in the source files.

Also, you are inconsistent about what your default is actually called. You say it is `who3` in the rule (`who3: ...`) but the command will actually build a task called `who` (`gcc -o who ...`).

Comment: Can I see an example of your suggestions?

Comment: @JFA: I'm suggesting changes to your makefile, which bit isn't clear?

Comment: By your first statement, you're saying that the first two lines should say: `who3:who3.o utmplib.o show.o' and the second line should reflect that as well?

Comment: Yes, the line `who3: ...` is listing the dependencies of `who3` and given that the function missing in your link step is defined in `show.c`/`show.o`, `who3` needs to link against and depend on `show.o` so you need it in the list of dependencies and the rule that makes it (`gcc -o who3...`).

Comment: What happens when you name something in the rule differently from the command? like say if I called the second target who3 but then called the command who3.o?

Comment: Ok, thank you, that worked. If who3.o depends on show.c, why do I not have to compile the object code with it?

Comment: SO is a great place to ask a question with an answer but a useless place to have an interactive mentoring session. It sounds like you need to start with some documentation. Here is a reasonable place to start: http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Rule-Introduction . If you have further specific questions you should ask as a new question, not as a comment to someone's answer.

Comment: In reality, `who3.o` does not depend on `show.c`. You've said it does in your makefile, but this isn't true. `who3.o` is built from `who3.c` and is completely independent of `show.c`.